# why toast message doesn't appear in my application at item clicked?

Tags: android, android-spinner, toast

I am working on a simple spinner. I wanna to show a toast message at any item clicked but it doesn't work.I don't know where the logical error is. Any help will be appreciated.
This is my code:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String itemSelected = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    int temp=Integer.parseInt(itemSelected);
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected: user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case 1:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected:  page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }

    // Showing selected spinner item
//Toast.makeText(adapter.getContext(), "Selected: " + itemSelected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: What are the items in spinner?

Comment: have you register Spinner with  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

Comment: if you un-comment the last line Toast does it shows when you click on spinner.

Comment: there are 2 items in the spinner just,,yeah i have been linked it with an adapter

Comment: Does this code even get called? Add a log line to find out.

Comment: thanks i get it ,there is no problem in my code ,the problem was i my emulator so i build new one thanks all

Comment: please check position.

Comment: Jusy FYI, if Show Notifications Checkbox is disabled in the Settings for particular app, it would not show Push Notifications as well as toast Notifications.